# How to replace Take(1) from Linq query

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

In a project I have to maintain, I have this Linq query using `Take(1)` :

```cs
(from workflow in db.Workflows
from search in db.Searches.Where(p => p.WorkflowId == workflow.WorkflowId).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { workflow, hasSearch = search.SearchId > 0 }).ToList();
```

When `Take(1)` is translated to SQL, it gives something like :

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WorkflowId ORDER BY WorkflowId)
```

which occurs to be lacking performance.

I guess the developer had a `SELECT TOP 1` in mind. But if use `FirstOrDefault` it would not return an IQueryable anymore. So, my question is : how can I rewrite the Linq query to keep the same purpose and not using `Take`, if possible ?

Comment: It's not about take but your query... Remove middle line and change`hasSearches` to `workflow.Searches.Any()` or `workflow.Searches.Count() > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If understand correctly needed result, query should be rewritten in this way:

```cs
var query =
    from workflow in db.Workflows
    select new 
    { 
        workflow, 
        hasSearch = db.Searches.Any(p => p.WorkflowId == workflow.WorkflowId)
    };
```